# Disable column resizing in <rich:extendedDataTable>

Tags: richfaces

I am using rich:extendedDataTable to display a table. But I need to disable the column resizing in this table. I have tried using width component in rich:column but I am getting the same thing. Even I have used css class to fix the column size that is also nnot worth. Any way out?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to disable column resizing within the `<rich:extendedDataTable>` tag itself. However, with a little CSS to hide the element that enables resizing, you can accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .extdt-hsep {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Note that this will only prevent the user from resizing columns. It will not stop the automatic ratio-based resizing that happens when you resize the grid itself (e.g.: when you resize the window and the grid has 100% width).